# Q# Application Template available for VS2022?

Tags: q#

Implemented Grover Search Tutorial using Q# in VS2019.

Moved to Windows 11 and also installed VS2022.

Project opens and runs OK in VS2022.
However code has no intellisense and color. i.e. program.qs appears as an ordinary text file.

Attempting new Project in VS2022 does not find any Q# Templates.
Is there something I need to do to install or is Q# Application Development not supported in VS2022 yet?

Comment: I would recommend to ask this question on StackExchange as it is related to general programming or software issue, not to quantum computing.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I think it belongs to StackOverflow as it doesn't require any knowledge about Quantum Computing to be answered.

Answer (score 2):

We just released today a preview version of the Microsoft Quantum Development Kit for Visual Studio 2022. I recommend you try it out.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=quantum.DevKit64

This is still in active development, so alternatively, you can also try using Visual Studio Code, which also has a Q# extension available.

Hope this helps.